# Is it possible to have a 3-way toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a 3-way toggle, something like [this](http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/css-toggle-switch/), but in 3 phases. Obviously this can't be done using a checkbox, as that's a boolean value, so I was wondering whether it would be possible to simulate such a thing using 3 radio buttons? Would such a thing be possible? And if so, is this the correct way of going about this?

Javascript is fine, by the way.

Comment: So you want one button with 3 states (clicking 3 times on the same button) but only using CSS?

Comment: @atmd So it would almost be a slider, but with only 3 states, left, middle and right.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516001/3-state-toggle-button

Comment: @atmd Javascript is fine, but a CSS solution would be best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tri-state Check box in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726096/tri-state-check-box-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have a tri-state button, but if you want a slider-type thing without JavaScript as you commented, just use a [`range`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range) input:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    $('#res').html(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" step="1" value="0" />
<div>Debug value: <span id="res"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

***Note:*** As this has now been down voted, I figured I'd point out that I posted this answer before [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) was added to the question, so please treat this as a pure HTML solution and nothing more.

Radio buttons are exactly how you'd do this:

```html
<label>State 1
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="State 1" />
</label>
<label>State 2
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="State 2" />
</label>
<label>State 3
  <input type="radio" name="radios" value="State 3" />
</label>
```

With this you have 3 states. In the above answer, the result is either State 1, State 2 or State 3.